# How to UV unwrap materials in the Material Library VX addon

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, uv, blend-files

I am applying the "Floor Wood" material from the Material Library VX addon to a box, but when I open the UV editor and unwrap my object I can't find the texture image to load into the background.

I need to UV Unwrap my object in order to change the scaling of the wood tiles and want the noise/bump/grain maps to also scale accordingly without having to manually change each map's values in the Mapping section of Textures tab.

Is there an easier way to scale all maps together? How do I unwrap and apply the textures from the Material Library VX addon into my object?

[image]

Main node group WO_Wood contents:

[image]

Material Node:

[image]

Here is my node setup in order to try and scale the values of the WO_Wood node.

[image]

**Potential solution?**
By going into the WO_Wood node group, and then into the Grain node group located inside, I was able to find the Mapping coordinates for the Brick Texture. However, I'm not sure if any changes to this automatically updates the bump/normal map?
[image]

Comment: To scale all textures together you can connect their Vector inputs together with Vector output of Mapping node. Note that you can also scale UV map islands instead. I'm not familiar with Material Library VX addon but I don't think editing of texture from this addon is in any way different from any other image texture

Comment: I may not be understanding this correctly as I'm still a beginner when it comes to Blender, but the nodes look a bit different for the addon. I attached images to the post for more information. In regards to UV Islands, I'm not able to load the material/image into the UV editor to begin with.

Comment: There aren't any image textures on the screenshot, glossy shader is mixed with diffuse and then again with glossy. There are 3 node groups though so they might have image textures inside (they are inside the group you showed above) *or* this addon creates the wood pattern procedurally and thus doesn't load any image files at all. At first you could try to use big WO_Wood node which stands for nodegroup and use its _Scale values to change scale of details

Comment: Thank you for your reply I just checked all of the node groups, and it is in fact procedural... and on the main WO_Wood node there isn't a scale setting for the tiles, only for the grain, variation, and pore values. However, I tried adding a Mapping node to the WO_Wood node (added a screenshot of my setup to the post) and it doesn't seem to affect the texture. Not sure if my node setup is correct. Is there any other way to scale the tiles or UV Unwrap the procedural texture the addon is producing?

Comment: To scale texture coordinates with Mapping node, add Texture Coordinates node to your tree and plug its output (Generated or Object if the material is procedural) into Mapping node input. However it seems nodegroup doesn't accept scaling texture coordinates as I don't see Vector input there. I would guess it assumes scaling details via multiple sliders provided already. If texture is generated procedurally changing UV mapping won't give much difference, it's better to use procedural power of texture created already. I think one should see nodesetup for more details (if you are allowed to share)

Comment: Thank you for you help Mr Zak I think i found the solution, I attached the new screenshot to the post. I went inside the WO_Wood node group and then from there I opened the Grain node group which gave me access to the brick texture used and the Mapping coordinates connected to it. However, I'm not sure if changing these values will automatically adjust the Bump/normal maps as well?